# How to select an element with no class and no id, that isn't always there?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's the situation - there is a `<li>` in my code that appears on certain conditions that I need to apply positioning to. It has no id, no class. I can't use nth-child, because sometimes it's not there so the next `<li>` gets selected, breaking my design. I've been on this for months now, it appears that Javascript is going to be the only answer here but I don't even know where to begin with that.

I suppose I could modify the source code to give the `<li>` an id, but that is not as elegant a solution as I'd like. Modifying the code that way will break the removal script for the plugin that inserts this code.

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please share your code and let us know exactly what your trying to do

Comment: How does it appear there? If you create it programmatically, you can have a direct reference to it.

Comment: can you make jsfiddle?

Comment: Nerf through all the list items and look at the content?

Comment: @bahgheera , do you want to catch the <li> in a variable? All <li>s or just one ?

Comment: You need to tell us under what conditions it appears. The answer is to give it a class when it appears and/or before it appears.

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is to find out the unique point of your li element, it could be id, class, attribute, style, innerText, or anything.
**for example:**

- the innerText of the element is 'i am li', just traverse all the li elements in your container, use `ele.innerText` to match it
- or the li has a backgroud: red which is unique, your may use `window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("background")` to traverse all the li elements in your container.

**update:**
First, if your li element has unique attribute,class,id, it will be easier.

```
<li class="test" id="test" name="handsome"></li>
li.test {}
li#test {}
li[name="handsome"] {} // ~=, ^=, $=, *= will also work
```

In your case, if the href attribute of the a tag is unique, you may do it like this simple example below.

```
function getTarget() {

    //find all the li elements in your container
    var $targetList = $('.container li');
    var $link;
    for( var i = 0; i < $targetList.length;i++) {
        $link = $($targetList[i]).find('a');

        //you can use any unique point to find the one
        if ($link.length && $link.attr('href') == 'xxxxxx') {
            return $targetList[i];
        }
    }
}

// the target is the li you want
target = getTarget();
```

Also, if you are not sure want about the href value, your may use `string.indexOf('http://www.test.com')`, if your innerText of li is unique, just change the judgement, it depends on your real situation ,just find the unique point and match it.

Comment: Ah, this is exactly what I was looking for - I knew js would handle it, but I'm not exactly proficient with js and it's statements. For those wondering, here is my code: WAIT - seriously, how do you type a cr/lf? Pressing enter just saves my comment. :/

Comment: Lets try this again - here is my code: 

'<li>There are <a href="http://www.theflipsideforum.com/index.php?action=admin;area=viewmembers;sa=browse;type=approve">4 members</a> awaiting approval.</li>'

See? No id, no class. I don't want to modify the code that generates this markup. Thanks for the replies everyone.

Comment: @bahgheera: You really ought to include that code in your question and not a comment on one of the answers. You should also include the surrounding markup - namely other li elements that may be there, as well as the parent ul.