# Select the only Element with no class or ID

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've seen both [this and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915504/jquery-select-element-that-has-no-class-or-id) [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30317214/how-to-select-an-element-with-no-class-and-no-id-that-isnt-always-there) but they're both Javascript-oriented.

I'm looking to select the only div which has no ID or Class.

Example:

```
<body>
<div class="X" ... />
<div class="Z" ... />
...
<div class="Y" ... />
<div>Select me</div>
<div id="footnote" ... /> <!-- Notice I have no class. -->
...
</body>
```

There will only ever be one `div` with no class *and* id.
The div may change places, or be not present.
No Javascript. However any language which can compile to CSS like SASS is fine.
The `div`s in question will *only* ever be directly under `<body>`.
I may not always know what classes or IDs there will be.

Comment: FYI, `div` tags aren't self closing. Needs `</div>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I write a CSS selector selecting elements NOT having a certain class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110300/can-i-write-a-css-selector-selecting-elements-not-having-a-certain-class)

Comment: Have you tried the `div:not([class])` in your CSS?

Comment: @JayMoy The problem here is that there may be multiple divs with no class, but they still have an ID.

Comment: You can stack the `:not` like in the answer below.. Depends if you know all the classes and id's I guess

Comment: @JayMoy Sadly, I do not know all the possible classes and IDs, but it appears I already got an answer in record time. Thanks!

Comment: More on div tags and self-closing syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455768/why-do-browsers-think-this-div-tag-isnt-immediately-ended

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `:not`:

CSS:

```
div:not([class]):not([id]) {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div></div>
<div class="shikaka"></div>
<div id="shikaka2"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qcq0qedj/

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
body > div:not([class]):not([id]) { }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dte4eLy4/)

Answer (score 1):

Ah... the beauty of :not.  (AKA - not:ugly)

```css
div:not([class]):not([id]) {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="X">...</div>
    <div>Select me</div>
    <div class="Z">...</div>
    <div class="Y">...</div>
    <div>Select me, too!</div>
    <div id="footnote">...</div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stevenventimiglia/53Lqekod/